# How do I pass advanced variables to Paypal PDT and IPN from hosted BuyNow Button

Tags: java, tomcat, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

My Paypal Hosted BuyButton applies a discount, done by adding this to advanced variables.

```
discount_rate=40
```

And that all works fine.

The problem is that in my IPN processing I check the user has paid correct amount by calling `request.getParameter(mc_gross)` and then I check the mc_gross figure against the expected figure, But mc_gross does not include the discount so this fails for discounted purchases.

I thought I could do

```
request.getParameter(discount_rate)
```

and then work out the net rate but it doesn't return the value.

So my question is how do get access to advanced_variable from IPN (and PDT), supplementary question is is there a standard variable that shows the amount actually paid by user (i.e after discount)

Comment: I'm guessing you are setting discount_rate=40 on the button itself when you create it via Paypal > Create a button.

Are you setting in a hidden input in the html as detailed here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#passing_custom_data

Comment: @TonyKennah I create as a part of creating button in Paypal, I don't have to have it as a hidden variable on website since each button has an id and Paypal can use this id to lookup all the details required.

Comment: advanced_variables is not something I use myself but at one stage I got all params via 
    `Enumeration<String> en = request.getParameterNames();`
Just to see what I was dealing with.  Maybe best to ask PayPal directly, I find them very good to deal with.

Comment: I did that but it wasn't passed, thanks anyway.I'm suprised that there do not seem to be any Paypal experts on this site.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS

It seems the discount amount would be retrieved with, request.getParameter(discount) which would be the total applied to the mc_gross_x.

You can get the rate by dividing the discount by the mc_gross_x.

Comment: i tried that, but it only applies to shopping cart not buy now button 'The total discount to be applied to a shopping cart in the currency of mc_currency.'